# Protected data members and data functions

Tags: c++, oop, access-specifier

when i declare a protected data member in a class that means its not accesible to the outer world but the derived class. My question is

> will it be accesible to a class that is derived from the derived class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, protected data members are accessible all the way down the inheritance hierarchy.

Protected data is usually better avoided. An alternative is to write protected *methods* that access the private data. This keeps the data encapsulated within a single class. It also makes it easy to set a breakpoint for changes to the data.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. (You could have simply tried that out, by the way.)